# Opening a CCScene in Lua from a C++ CCScene in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, lua, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to use Lua scripting and Cocos2d-x together and I'm having a bit of trouble making things work properly.

**Part 1:**
I have two `CCScene` classes, `HomeScene` and `GameScene`. `HomeScene` is written in **C++** while `GameScene` is written in **Lua Script**. Now what I want to do is to create a 'link' between these two scenes. At a certain point in the life of `HomeScene`, it will create `GameScene` and `GameScene` will replace `HomeScene` (something like CCDirector::replaceScene). Then after that, during the life of `GameScene`, it returns back to `HomeScene`.

**Part 2:**
Aside from that, `HomeScene` needs to pass some information, let's say `time`, into `GameScene`. `GameScene` will then use this `time` value for further processing. When `GameScene` returns back to `HomeScene`, it passes yet another bit of data, let's say `score`, back to `HomeScene`.

So, the question is, are both parts possible using Lua binding in cocos2d-x? If so, how should I go about implementing it?

**What I've tried:**
I have created a small Lua script file to test if what I'm thinking can work.

```
local function main()
    local visibleSize = CCDirector:sharedDirector():getVisibleSize()
    local origin = CCDirector:sharedDirector():getVisibleOrigin()

    local function createLayer()
        local function doGoBack()
            CCDirector:sharedDirector():popScene()
        end

        local layer = CCLayer:create()

        local btn = CCMenuItemImage:create( "btn0.jpg", "btn1.jpg" )
        btn:setPosition( ccp( visibleSize.width * 0.50, visibleSize.height * 0.50 ) )
        btn:registerScriptTapHandler( doGoBack )

        local menu = CCMenu:createWithItem( btn )
        menu:setPosition( ccp( 0, 0 ) )
        layer:addChild( menu, 1 )

        cclog( "createdLayer" )

        return layer
    end

    -- run
    local sceneGame = CCScene:create()
    sceneGame:addChild( createLayer() )
    CCDirector:sharedDirector():pushScene( sceneGame )
end
```

Then I created a CCScene that will call this script

```
void TestScene::runLuaScript() {
    std::string luaPath = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils() -> fullPathForFilename( "test.lua" );
    CCString * luaCode = CCString::createWithContentsOfFile( luaPath.c_str() );
    CCLuaEngine::defaultEngine() -> executeString( luaCode -> getCString() );
}
```

When I tried to run it, the Lua script is executed properly (the `cclog` output is properly printed) but the objects on the Lua scene is not visible and only a black screen appears (because `TestScene` is an empty scene).

I'm feeling what I'm thinking is possible, it's just that I am implementing it wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the above code was a logic error.

The Lua-scripted `CCScene` was being added before the C++ `CCScene` was even executed. Removing `TestScene::runLuaScript()` on the `init()` method of the `CCLayer` and calling the method outside the `init()` method did the trick. The Lua-scripted `CCScene` was properly being executed after that.